# C Why the casting of malloc and an explanation?

Tags: malloc, byte, internal, multiplication

Ok I asked this the other day. But the answers I recieved when asked made me realize I was not fit to question it yet until I did some hard research.

So here I am yet again to retry this....

In examples of malloc I seen something as such...

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int ptr_doe;

        ptr_doe = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
```

I read that it was not neccesary for the:

```
    (this *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

And that only

```
    (int *) malloc(sizeof(\\this));
```

is neccesary. Is the casting before calling the malloc function ever neccesary?
And how do we know how much memory we need to allocate and what the hell is this?

```
    malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

is it multiplying 4 bytes by 10? and when is it neccesary to use malloc? How does it work internally? Thanks for any help guys

Comment: I'm not asking for help on figuring out an error im asking is it neccesary and that was to point out where I was specifically talking about.

Comment: You only need to cast the result of malloc if you're using C++ - for C you should most definitely never cast the result of malloc - see duplicate question: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

> Is the casting before calling the malloc function ever neccesary?

If you use a currect compiler, No. See answers to [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

2.

> how do we know how much memory we need to allocate

It depends on your needs.

3.

```
malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

means to allocate memory big enough to store 10 `int` value.

4.

> is it multiplying 4 bytes by 10?

If `sizeof(int)` equals 4, yes.

5.

> when is it neccesary to use malloc?

If only at runtime you can know how much memory your program needs.

6.

> How does it work internally?

Briefly, `malloc()` will ask operating system for enough memory, record some information it needs, and return you a pointer to the start of that memory segment.